# Rest API bearer authorization

Tags: processmaker-api

PM4 Community edition. Installed with bitnami stack.

Trying to access services through API but getting 401 : Unauthenticated error

```
let response = await Axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://111.111.111.111/api/1.0/processes',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + PM_TOKEN,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        })
```

Same error is generated through swagger /api/documentation

I am generating API Token under new user => API Tokens. User is part of Requesters group. I haven't done anything else, should I?

At least I can see that scopes for JWT token is empty.

Answer (score -1):

In ProcessMaker ,.I think that the best solution is to work with data connectors. See the following links to obtain API services.

[Data Connectors](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/designing-processes/data-connector-management/what-is-a-data-connector)

[API service](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/processmaker-api-documentation/access-processmaker-api-documentation#test-api-endpoints-from-the-api-documentation)

The last link contains information on the endpoints available for API services. Be careful when constructing the URL for the API call.

Comment: this doesn't answer a question